# Как сделать анимированый градиент?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать анимированный фон с переливающимся градиентом, как в инстаграм?

Comment: Пробовали создать background с файлом xml?

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, как в инстаграме, но предположу, что что-нибудь вроде этого:

**res/drawable/start_gradient_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#3B5998"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

**res/drawable/end_gradient_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#3B5998"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

**res/drawable/animated_gradient_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start_gradient_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/end_gradient_background" />
</transition>
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/animated_gradient_background" >
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private final int duration = 2000;

private void repeatTransition(final TransitionDrawable transition, final boolean direction) {
    Handler hand = new Handler();
    hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(direction) {
                transition.startTransition(duration);
            }
            else {
                transition.reverseTransition(duration);
            }
            repeatTransition(transition, !direction);
        }
    }, duration);
}

View main = (View) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
final TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) main.getBackground();
repeatTransition(transition, true);
```

Возможно, есть и более правильные или изящные способы зациклить TransitionDrawable, но я их не знаю.